# Why does my accuracy change a lot when I use a dense layer in an LSTM?

Tags: regression, time-series, multivariate-analysis, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using one to many LSTM approach, where,

1. I have an input layer, an LSTM layer, and a dense layer in Model 1.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyP2F.png)
2. I have an input and an LSTM layer in my Model 2.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axAUQ.png)

You can visualize both the models down below.

[image: LSRM model 1]
[image: LSTM Model 2]

When I observe the RMSE for both the models, Model 1 has a lesser RMSE than Model 2, and when I visualize the prediction for a test sample, Model 1 performs far better than Model2.
[image: Prediction for a test sample using Model1]
[image: Prediction for a test sample using Model2]

The only difference between these 2 models is a dense layer. What I can not understand is, how is a dense layer influencing the model soo much?

Code for Model 1-

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(Input(batch_shape=(None,1,7)))
model.add(LSTM(max_length))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: You did not say much about the data and the hyperparamters. My first guess would be: the model with the dense layer has more parameters. Isn't it overfitting?

Comment: I used default hyperparameters.

Input - 7 input parameters (standardized mean 0 and sigma 1) (Material thickness, velocity, etc.).

Number of samples - 2000 (using 80% from this for training). Input parameters are uniformly distributed. 

Output - Predict intrusion value of 651 time steps. 

If it is overfitting, then should not the validation dataset perform very bad compared to train? 

RMSE for Model 1 - 0.0473 (Train), 0.5209(Test).

RMSE for Model 2 - 0.5987(Train), 0.7796(Test).